# Marketing Cloud - acquire an access token

Tags: oauth2, marketing-cloud-connect

I am trying to define HTTP Client connection in Dell Boomi to make REST API Calls for Marketing Cloud. I am having issues in configuring Access Token URL & Authorization Token URL in the HTTP Client connection configuration in Dell Boomi.

Access Token URL as https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken does not seem to be working. When trying to generate the Access Token with this as the URL application is redirecting back to Dell Boomi platform and shows the platform landing page and without any access token information. Please let me know if I am missing something. Please refer to the below screenshot.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: At this time Dell Boomi lacks an Application Connector for Salesforce Marketing Cloud / Exact Target.

To be clear, that means, I have to use up at least two connectors to connect to Marketing Cloud / Exact Target!

Figure out OAuth using HTTP Client, back to SOAP XML for half the API and then back to REST API for the other half. And I have to keep my integration process looping and routing between them as needed.


That seems like a lot of gymnastics?


As far as I can tell they also lack starter templates in the Process Library to help connect to Marketing Cloud?

Comment: Dell's competitor, Informatica, have a much more compelling offer, no gymnastics and all for about the cost of the Boomi connectors I would use up here. Might be worth a look, even for just this integration scenario.

Comment: Use the client credentials as the grant type and follow this [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/integration-s2s-client-credentials.htm)